# Make form redirect users after posting

Tags: javascript, forms

I need to change a form so that instead of reloading the page after submitting it, it redirects the user to another page.

This is the form I'm talking about:

```
<form class="questionform" name="questionform-0" id="questionform-0">

<textarea class="question-box" cols="12" rows="5"  id="question-box-' . $questionformid . '" name="title" type="text" maxlength="200" size="28"></textarea>

<input type="text" class="ubicacion" value="" name="question">

<input  type="button" name="ask" value="Publicar" onclick="askquestion('questionform-0'); window.location.reload(true);">
```

I want to remove window.location.reload and change it for something that redirects users to the page their comment will appear.

The problem is that it's not simply a static. So I have no idea how to do it. The URL I want to send users to is:

www.chusmix.com/s?=(content of the second field)

How do I do it? Anyway thanks for any info or whatever that points me on the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use javascript for this purpose. You only need to set the **action** attribute of the **form** tag. It tells where the form information will be sent. So in your case it will be:

```
<form action="http://www.chusmix.com/s">
```

Also if you want to send the variables through the URL like: http://www.chusmix.com/s?variable=someValue

You need to set the **method** attribute as **get** so it will look like this:

```
<form action="http://www.chusmix.com/s" method="get">
```

If you don't want the data sent to be visible set the **method** to **post**, note that there are different advantages for each method so i recommend you read more about this if this form is an vital part of your webpage.

The variable names that appear in the url `http://domain.com?**variable**=` will depend on the inputs name `<input type="text" name="**variable**" />`

For more information on how forms work you can go to:

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_form.asp
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php

Comment: Mmmm action no tiene que ver con donde va la info? Lo probe pero deja de funcionar el form. Lo unico que quiero es redireccionar al usuario despues de que poste además de eso no quiero cambiar nada. De todas formas gracias

Comment: estas ocupando PHP para manejar los campos? si es asi despues de procesar la informacion puedes hacer algo como <?php header("Location: http://dominio.com/s?variable=$variable"); ?>

Answer (score 0):

You can ad an action:

```
<form action="redirection_url.php" method="POST" class="questionform" name="questionform-0" id="questionform-0">
```

I think you can use both absolute and relative url. Also note that I've added

method="POST" - which defines how the data from the form will be sent, as you already send some data with GET method (that's the stuff after ? in your url) - so this should work pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use the `action` attribute in the `<form>` tag, you may redirect the user using `window.location` (you will probably want to do this inside the `askquestion` method, not in the `onclick` attribute).

```
window.location = "http://www.chusmix.com/s?=" + inputValue;
```

Comment: How do I put it inside the askquestion? Thanks

Comment: Just paste that line in the end of the function.